# Aggregating datetime64[ns] and float columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, aggregate, python-datetime

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like the one below.

| racer | race_time_1 | race_time_2 | 1st_Place | 2nd_Place | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| joe shmo | 0:24:12 | NaN | 1 | 0 |  |
| joe shmo | NaN | 0:32:43 | 0 | 0 |  |
| joe shmo | NaN | 0:30:21 | 0 | 1 |  |
| sally sue | NaN | 0:29:54 | 1 | 0 |  |

I would like to group all the rows by racer name to show me total race times, places, etc.

I am attempting to do this with

```
df.groupby('racer', dropna=True).agg('sum')
```

Each column was initially loaded as an object dtype which causes issues when aggregating numbers with anything that isn't a null value.

For the race_time values, after lots of searching I tried changing the columns to datetime64[ns] dtypes with dummy data for day/month/year, but instead of summing the race_time columns they are dropped from the dataframe when the groupby function is called.

The opposite issue arises when I change 1st_Place and 2nd_place to float dtypes. When groupby is called, the aggregation will work as expected, but every other column is dropped (the object columns that is).

For example, with joe shmo I would want to see:

| racer | race_time_1 | race_time_2 | 1st_Place | 2nd_Place |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| joe shmo | 0:24:12 | 1:03:04 | 1 | 1 |

How can I get pandas to aggregate my dataframe like this?

Comment: Maybe you can fillna with 0 and then do groupby.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#function for formating timedeltas
def f(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds))

#convert Place columns to numeric
cols1 = df.filter(like='Place').columns
df[cols1] = df[cols1].apply(pd.to_numeric)

#convert time columns to timedeltas and then to unix time
cols = df.filter(like='time').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna('0').apply(pd.to_timedelta).astype(np.int64)

#aggregate sum
df = df.groupby('racer', dropna=True).sum()

#convert timedeltas to times with formating
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x).map(f))
print (df)
          race_time_1 race_time_2  1st_Place  2nd_Place
racer                                                  
joe shmo     00:24:12    01:03:04          1          1
sally sue    00:00:00    00:29:54          1          0
```

Comment: Hey Jezrael - First of all, thank you very much for the response and trying to work through this problem with me. Your code looks promising, but the issue I run into when trying to implement it is with the line "df[cols] = df[cols].fillna('0').apply(pd.to_timedelta).astype(np.int64)" which seems to always result in "ValueError: Value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta or convertible, not time" despite efforts to manipulate the source columns to reflect one of these values. Do you know what could be causing this error and how I would resolve the issue in this case?

Comment: @ForyinOuroboros - What is `print(df.filter(like='time').head().to_dict(orient='list'))` ? Because it seems data related problem.

Comment: Hey Jezrael - Ultimately it was a data-related problem that I was able to resolve by applying pd.to_timedelta earlier in the process. Thank you so much for your assistance on this case, it was very helpful!